# Differentiating $|z|^2$ in the complex plane

Tags: complex-analysis, derivatives, complex-numbers

I am just wondering about the possibility of differentiating $|z|^2$, where $z=x+iy$.

How to do this?

Comment: Use the definition of derivative.

Comment: I conclude that is not differentciated by using cauchy-riemann equation. but I not sure.

Comment: Yes, you can indeed verify that $x^2+y^2$ does not satisfy Cauchy-Riemann equations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $|z|^2$ is always real, we have $\frac{\partial v}{\partial x}=\frac{\partial v}{\partial y}=0$ everywhere, so the only way the Cauchy-Riemann-equations can be satisfied is if *all* the partial derivatives vanish everywhere. But then the function would be constant, which $|z|^2$ is not.